# Stable build of React-native + Relay.js

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, relayjs

I'm looking for a solution that has been tested in production environment.

Particularly combination of React-Native with Relay.js

The problem why it doesn't work out of the box is described here:
https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/26

Best Regards,

Eugene

Comment: Keep an eye on that issue – this is being actively worked on. When compatibility is a reality, someone should answer this question, pointing to the version of React Native / Relay that work together.

Comment: Looks like there is an additional work left to merge in the master branches. Let's see if we can get the stable edition in March. Fingers crossed.

Comment: just to confirm my words, https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/26#issuecomment-187810004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relay 0.7.3 and React Native 0.22 are now compatible.

Announcement: https://twitter.com/steveluscher/status/707720501175697408
Example app: https://github.com/facebook/relay/tree/master/examples/TodoMVC

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it yet, but I found this, which claims to be a fix for Relay issue #26: https://github.com/lenaten/react-native-relay.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not production ready. And it's from the same issue discussion on github.